# Force SimpleXML node to always be an array, even if just 1 element in it

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Let's say I want a Place to have a list of phone numbers.
Some places will have 1 phone number, and some will have more than one. Others won't have one at all.

The problem is that this:

```
$xml->addChild('phone_number','555.555.5555');
```

creates a non-iterable phone_number text node:

```
$response->xml->phone_number;
```

But this:

```
$xml->addChild('phone_number','555.555.5555');
$xml->addChild('phone_number','555.555.5556');
```

creates an iterable array of phone_number:

```
$response->xml->phone_number[0];
$response->xml->phone_number[1];
```

This puts an unnecessary burden on the client. They have to detect if the result is iterable or not, and modify their code accordingly.

It would be MUCH better if I could always send back an interable array, even if it had 0 or 1 items in it... but I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this. In Perl I believe it's called "forcearray", but I haven't found an equivalent for PHP, which is waht i need.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use this fancy, magic interface (`$obj->xml->phone_number[x]`) and use [`SimpleXMLElement::children()` method](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) which always returns iterable object.

Answer (score 2):

you should consider this

```
<phone_numbers>
  <phone_number>555.555.5555</phone_number>
</phone_numbers>
```

this is more flexible

beside the `children()` method, you can also consider [`xpath`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)
which always will yields an array to be return

example

```
$xml = <<<XML
<person>
  <phone_numbers>
    <phone_number>555.555.5555</phone_number>
  </phone_numbers>
</person>
XML;

$obj  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$tels = $obj->xpath("//phone_numbers/*");

/* even more simple */
$tels = $obj->phone_numbers->children();
```

Comment: I have done that but I have the same problem. You would think that the result would be: $response->xml->phone_numbers->phone_number[0];  but when there's only one phone number the result is actually: $response->xml->phone_numbers->phone_number;

Comment: method xpath or children will allow return an array

Comment: @lo_fye -- sorry, might not your desired answer, to make it loop-able, code changes is expected